# Powershell - add string after 14th 24th 36th 46th and 55th character following a word

Tags: powershell, replace, insert

We have many files which contain header lines beginning with HDR that need to be updated for clarity.  I am new to coding in powershell and would like to know how I can update the code below to accomplish this.
Example:
Before:

```
HDR,9345561421,20220510,1536838657,20220510,5550810,111003
```

After:

```
HDR, INV-9345561421, DATE-20220510, PO-1536838657, DATE-20220510, ORDER-5550810, CUST-111003
```

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\SFTP\Whirlpool\Invoices\*.csv' | ForEach {
     (Get-Content $_) | ForEach  {          
    $_.Insert(HDR, ,"INV-").Insert(HDR, .........., ,"NVDATE-").Insert(HDR, .........., ........,  ,"PO-").Insert(HDR, .........., ........, ..........,   ,"PODATE-").Insert(HDR, .........., ........, .........., ........,   ,"ORDER-").Insert(HDR, .........., ........, .........., ........, .......,   ,"SHIPTO-")
} | Set-Content $_
}
```

The solution below provided by Santiago Squarzon worked perfectly.

```
$head = 'INV', 'DATE', 'PO', 'DATE', 'ORDER', 'CUST'
foreach($csv in Get-ChildItem 'C:\SFTP\Whirlpool\Invoices\*.csv') {
    $newContent = switch -Regex -File $csv.FullName {
        '^HDR' {
            $i = [ref] 0
            [regex]::Replace($_, ',', { ', ' + $head[$i.Value++] + '-' })
            continue
        }
        Default { $_ }
    }
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $csv.FullName -Value $newContent
}
```

Comment: The Csvs always have the same number of headers? and, just to clarify, you only want to change the first line of the Csvs (the header) not all lines

Comment: Hello.  Yes.  There will always be 6 items of the same length after the word HDR in each header.  However the header line represents the beginning of a new invoice and it can appear several times within a file as there are several different invoices within each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace any line starting with **HDR** and said line has the same number of items comma-separated (5 commas in total), you could use this call to [`Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)):

```
$head = 'INV', 'DATE', 'PO', 'DATE', 'ORDER', 'CUST'
$line = 'HDR,9345561421,20220510,1536838657,20220510,5550810,111003'
$i = [ref] 0
[regex]::Replace($line, ',', { ', ' + $head[$i.Value++] + '-' })

# Produces this output:
# HDR, INV-9345561421, DATE-20220510, PO-1536838657, DATE-20220510, ORDER-5550810, CUST-111003
```

You can combine above logic with a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) using the `-File` parameter to read your files and the `-Regex` parameter to target the lines starting with **HDR** (`^HDR`):

```
$head = 'INV', 'DATE', 'PO', 'DATE', 'ORDER', 'CUST'
foreach($csv in Get-ChildItem 'C:\SFTP\Whirlpool\Invoices\*.csv') {
    $newContent = switch -Regex -File $csv.FullName {
        '^HDR' {
            $i = [ref] 0
            [regex]::Replace($_, ',', { ', ' + $head[$i.Value++] + '-' })
            continue
        }
        Default { $_ }
    }
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $csv.FullName -Value $newContent
}
```